# Problems using fluentlenium with dynamic generated content

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, playframework, slickgrid

I am doing tests with fluentlenium to my application, but some errors are happening. I ‘m using Play Framework and Slickgrid to create my grid. Slickgrid create the grid dynamically in javascript.
The structure that is created seems like this:

```
<div id=”grid”>
<div class=”header”>
    <div class=”slickgrid-column-header column-1”>Column 1 </div>
    <div class=”slickgrid-column-header column-2”>Column 2 </div>
    <div class=”slickgrid-column-header column-2”>Column 2 </div>
</div>
<div class=”viewport”>
    <div class=”canvas”>
        <div class=”slick-row row-1”>
            <div class=”slick-cell l0 r0> Column 1 Row 1</div>
            <div class=”slick-cell l1 r1> Column 2 Row 1</div>
            <div class=”slick-cell l2 r2> Column 3 Row 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class=”slick-row row-2”>
            <div class=”slick-cell l0 r0> Column 1 Row 2</div>
            <div class=”slick-cell l1 r1> Column 2 Row 2</div>
            <div class=”slick-cell l2 r2> Column 3 Row 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Normally, when you see your source code with fluentlenium, you can see all source code, but in my case, some slickgrid code lines are missing. And this missing lines are the lines that I need. 
This code creates a simple test that get the page source.

```
@Test
   public final void fakeTest() {
         final int port = 3333;
     running(testServer(port, fakeApplication()), HTMLUNIT, 
         new Callback<TestBrowser>() {
          @Override
         public void invoke(final TestBrowser browser) throws Throwable {
                browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333/fake");
                    System.out.println(browser.pageSource());
         }
          });
   }
```

The output seems like this:

```
<html>
<head> <title> </title> </head>
<body>
    <div id=”grid>
        <div class=”header”>
            <div class=”slickgrid-column-header column-1”>Column 1 </div>
            <div class=”slickgrid-column-header column-2”>Column 2 </div>
            <div class=”slickgrid-column-header column-2”>Column 2 </div>
            </div>
                <div class=”viewport”>
            <div class=”canvas”></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How you can see, the cells didn’t appear and I can’t get the cell FluentWebElement to simulate clicks or get the cell value.

Answer (score 1):

You have the comportement you have write :

- go to the page
- print the source immediatly

What's happend there : the Slickgrid stuff is not generated yet. If you want so, you have to wait.

So use the await api with something like between the goTo(page) and :

```
await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(".slick-row").isPresent()
```

or anything you think more appropriate. There it will wait at most 5 seconds until a element with the class slick-row has been found.